# Unable to add data into mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using Mongoose to create a schema and attempting to add data to mongoDB via Postman and it is adding empty data to the db. I'm assuming my issue is the way the data is parsed from browser to server here is my app.js setup.

**what is added to DB**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57846282c7b5f51d4c1742a9"), "__v" : 0 }
```

**Here is the app.js file**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  =   require('multer');        
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/growlingRabbit');
var Page = require('./models/growling_rabbit_page_text.js');

var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);


var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');

app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});

app.post('/api/text',function(req,res){
    var text = new Page();     
        text.name = req.body.name;  

        text.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Text Added!' });
        });

});



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


module.exports = app;
```

**Here is the model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema; 
var pageSchema   = new Schema({
    homePage: String,
    communityPage: String,
    eventPage: String,
    contactPage: String,
    galleryPage: String });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Page', pageSchema);;
```

Help, I'm sure it is something painfully obvious, unfortunately I cannot find it.

Comment: Any error while running this script?

Comment: No errors when running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you create a `Page` with

```
var text = new Page();     
text.name = req.body.name;
```

but your schema has no `name` property. 
Change your schema like so:

```
var pageSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    homePage: String,
    communityPage: String,
    eventPage: String,
    contactPage: String,
    galleryPage: String });
```

---

Another problem could be using the wrong option for posting the data via Postman.
Ensure that `x-www-form-urlencoded` is used when testing your node API

[image: Postman]

Comment: Thx! Big brain fart there, unfortunately this does not fix the issue.

Comment: Can you test whether it saves something if you set text.name to a constant string for testing purposes?

Comment: Yep, it saves a constant.

Comment: Well then your guess is probably right with having the issue with parsing the data. I updated the answer with another problem I also had in the past when using Postman with my node API tests